# MySQL Triggers - Don't update if outside in range of attribute (int)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create (what I think) should be a basic trigger.

Essentially if someone tries putting a value in for a record that is outside the range of the trigger, then it would refuse the update.

Table is called: People

Field concerned is: age (int)

```
     CREATE TRIGGER max_age_trigger BEFORE UPDATE
     ON People
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
         IF People.age <0 OR People.age>150 THEN
           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
               SET MESSAGE_TEXT = `Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)`;
        END IF;
      END
```

MySQL is throwing an error at line 7. However i'm not understanding where i'm going wrong. I'm new to triggers and still getting my head around it.

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7*

If you could help/assist me in my code, that would be of great help :)

Answer (score 1):

> [13.1.16 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)
>
> ...
>
> Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table
>   (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and
>   NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is
>   updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to
>   be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.
>
> ...

Also change:

```sql
-- SET MESSAGE_TEXT = `Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)`;
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)';
```

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`//
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `People`//

CREATE TABLE `People` (
  `age` INT
)//

INSERT INTO `People`
  (`age`)
VALUES
  (20)//

CREATE TRIGGER `max_age_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `People`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- IF People.age <0 OR People.age>150 THEN
  IF NEW.`age` < 0 OR NEW.`age` > 150 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    -- SET MESSAGE_TEXT = `Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)`;
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)';
  END IF;
END//

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(`p_age` INT)
BEGIN
  UPDATE `People` SET `age` = `p_age`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```sql
mysql> CALL `sp_test`(200);
ERROR 1644 (45000): Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)
```

Recommendation, for an AGE perhaps the INT data type is very large, try a better dimension. See [Chapter 11 Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html).